# Как можно получить правильно текст?

Tags: jquery, dom, javascript

Добрый вечер. Вопрос такой. Есть следующая html разметка:

> <div
> data-id="'.$data['id'][$i].'"><div><b>'.$data['key'][$i].'</b><i>'.$data['comment'][$i].'</i></div>'.$data['value'][$i].'<i></i></div>

Задача: получить текст, что находится на месте переменной `$data['value'][$i]`.
Пробовал с помощью text() и html(). Не помогло.
                                                             Спасибо за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Костыль средней тяжести:

```
var txt = $("tvoydiv").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Создаем клона, удаляем у него потомков, забираем текст.

Comment: Практически так само думал, правда я думал есть проще способ. Спасибо за ответ!